# explode an array of delimited strings into two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, function, explode

I have the following array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 10-7
        [1] => 11-3
        [2] => 11-7
        [3] => 12-3
        [4] => 12-7
        [5] => 13-3
        [6] => 13-7
        [7] => 14-3
        [8] => 14-7
        [9] => 15-7
    )
```

that I need to split into two arrays using `"-"` as delimiter:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 11
        [3] => 12
        [4] => 12
        [5] => 13
        [6] => 13
        [7] => 14
        [8] => 14
        [9] => 15
    )
```

and

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 7
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 7
        [5] => 3
        [6] => 7
        [7] => 3
        [8] => 7
        [9] => 7
    )
```

Is there anything like `array_explode` that does what I want? or a combination of php `array` functions? I'd like to do this without going through my own `for`/`each` loop, if possible, or at least minimize having to reinvent the wheel when something (pseudo)in-built is already out there. I already did this with a for loop. But I can't shake the feeling that there's a more elegant way that smartly uses array functions or anything of that kind. Thanks so much, guys.

*Additional info:*

Not sure if it matters, but I'm actually after the unique values in the resulting two arrays:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 12
        [3] => 13
        [4] => 14
        [5] => 15
    )
```

and

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 3
    )
```

The unique values don't need to be sorted, the keys may be preserved or not, and the legal values of the first array range from `0` to `23`, while those of the second `1` to `7`. However it's possible to have values other than these (`0` to `23` and `1` to `7` or even undelimited stray strings or other data types beyond my control), which I would definitely want to throw out.

Comment: What you have tried??? tell us

Comment: oh yeap, i already did this with a for loop. but i can't shake the feeling that there's a more elegant way that smartly uses array functions.

Comment: @AnaBan Add that info to the question, so that nobody answers the wrong question.

Comment: @Ikke done. (added more info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic bullet you're looking for is [`array_reduce()`](http://us.php.net/array_reduce), e.g. (PHP 5.3+):

```
list( $left, $right ) = array_reduce( $input,
  function( $memo, $item ) {
    list( $l, $r ) = explode( '-', $item );
    $memo[0][$l] = $memo[1][$r] = true;
    return $memo;
  },
  array( array(), array() )
);

var_dump( array_keys( $left ), array_keys( $right ) );
```

You can [see it in action here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d2seGb).

With PHP <5.3 you'll have to declare the function ahead of time:

```
function my_reducer( $memo, $item ) {
  list( $l, $r ) = // ...
  // ... as above ...
}

list( $left, $right ) = array_reduce(
  $input, 'my_reducer',
  array( array(), array() )
);
```

Comment: Glad it was useful. PHP's functional-style array functions (`array_reduce`, `array_map`, `array_filter`, etc.) are among PHP's most useful and most under-utilized functions.

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/TpVUIhM7

```
<?php
    $array = array('7-10','7-11','5-10');
    foreach($array as $a){list($x[], $y[]) = explode("-", $a);}
    print_r(array_unique($x));
    print_r(array_unique($y));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is your Solution, Try to implement following code.

Should work for you.

```
$main_array =   array( 
        '0' => '10-7',
        '1' => '11-3',
        '2' => '11-7',
        '3' => '12-3',
        '4' => '12-7',
        '5' => '13-3',
        '6' => '13-7',
        '7' => '14-3',
        '8' => '14-7',
        '9' => '15-7',
        );

foreach($main_array as $key=>$value)
{
    $arr_value      =   explode('-',$value);
    $arr_temp1[]    =   $arr_value[0];
    $arr_temp2[]    =   $arr_value[1];  
}
$arr_temp1_unique   = array_unique($arr_temp1);
$arr_temp2_unique   = array_unique($arr_temp2);


print "<pre>";
print_r($main_array);
print_r($arr_temp1);
print_r($arr_temp2);

print_r($arr_temp1_unique);
print_r($arr_temp2_unique);
print "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no suitable PHP function that you can use in this situation.

Functions like `array_walk()` and `array_map()` result in a single array, not in multiple arrays.

You said you already have tried a sollution with a loop, but for the sake of helping, here is how I would solve this:

```
//$data contains the array you want to split
$firstItems = array();
$secondItems = array();

foreach($data as $item)
{
    list($first, $second) = explode('-', $item, 2);
    $firstItems[$first] = true;
    $secondItems[$second] = true;    
}

//Now you can get the items with array_keys($firstItems) and array_keys($secondItems);
```

I'm treating the PHP array as a `set` by setting the keys instead of the values. This makes that you don't have to use `array_unique()` to get the unique items.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($old_array as $array){
    $new_2d_array = explode('-', $array);
    $new_array_1[] = $new_2d_array[0];
    $new_array_2[] = $new_2d_array[1];  
}
$new_array_1 = array_unique($new_array_1);
$new_array_2 = array_unique($new_array_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if "The unique values don't need to be sorted, the keys may be preserved or not", then I am going to apply the values to the result arrays as both keys and values to ensure uniqueness without any more function calls after the initial loop.

You can use `explode()` or `sscanf()`.  `explode()` has a simpler syntax and only requires the glue substring, whereas `sscanf()` must parse the whole string and therefore needs a more complicated pattern to match with.

If you didn't need uniqueness, you could simply use:

```
$hours = [];
$days = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    sscanf($item, '%d-%d', $hours[], $days[]);
}
```

or

```
$hours = [];
$days = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    [$hours[], $days[]] = explode('-', $item);
}
```

To ensure uniqueness, just use the isolated values as keys as well.

`sscanf()` allows you to cast the parsed values directly to integers ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/APcne))

```
$hours = [];
$days = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    [0 => $hour, 1 => $day, 0 => $hours[$hour], 1 => $days[$day]] = sscanf($item, '%d-%d');
}
```

`explode()` will only produce string-type values. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GHQ5D))

```
$hours = [];
$days = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    [0 => $hour, 1 => $day, 0 => $hours[$hour], 1 => $days[$day]] = explode('-', $item);
}
```

All of the above snippets rely on "array destructuring" syntax instead of calling `list()`.  If you are wondering why the keys are repeated while destructuring, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71807960/2943403).